# How can I improve my edge detection program to hit smaller details?

Tags: java, image, edge-detection

I have written an edge detection program in Java and it works well but it has its limits. Here is a before and after photo using it.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

My method for this checks to see the differences between each pixel and if the difference is great enough it will mark it black and if it is similar enough it will mark it white.

```
    public Image edgeDetection() {
    Color[][] newImg = new Color[image.length][image[0].length];
    int x = 2;//higher = less sensitive; lower = more sensitive
    for (int r = 0; r < image.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < image[r].length; c++) {
            int red = image[r][c].getRed();
            int blue = image[r][c].getBlue();
            int green = image[r][c].getGreen();
            if(r < image.length - 1 && c < image[r].length) {
                if(image[r][c].getRed() - image[r + 1][c].getRed() > x || image[r][c].getRed() - image[r +  1][c].getRed() < -x ) {//
                    if(image[r][c].getBlue() - image[r +  1][c].getBlue() > x || image[r][c].getRed() - image[r +  1][c].getRed() < -x ) {
                        if(image[r][c].getGreen() - image[r +  1][c].getGreen() > x || image[r][c].getRed() - image[r +  1][c].getRed() < -x ) {
                            newImg[r][c] = new Color(0, 0, 0);
                        }
                        else {
                            newImg[r][c] = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        newImg[r][c] = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    newImg[r][c] = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                }
            }
            else {
                newImg[r][c] = new Color(red, green, blue);
            }
        }
    }
    return new Image (newImg);
}
```

Currently, I have the x value set to 2 so there are more black pixels than white, if I were to increase that number you would see the opposite. It seems there is no X value that I can set it to that would make the image look more like the original but in this edge style. Right now I am looking for advice on how to make the image look sharper despite it only being black and white. I want to capture the smaller intricacies in images like this one. If there is anything else I missed I can provide more code. Thanks!

Also, this project is just for fun so no worries if this isn't something that's possible with my code!

Comment: Looks like simple horizontal differentiation. 1) Also compare vertically, i.e. `p[r][c]` to `p[r][c+1]`. 2) You're repeating a lot of checks for the same condition. You should compact that, like using `Math.abs` or custom methods that drastically shorten/simplify your code. 3) It looks to me you're mismatching color checks in your long if cascades, matching red on red, then blue on red, then green on red. Maybe that's the trick behind your algorithm, but I don't understand it. 4) Maybe convert the whole image to a grayscale image/array first `(red+blue+green)/3`, so your detection is easier.

Comment: @JayC667 thank you! all of those things make sense. For number 3 though that was part of what I was going for, but if it doesn't make sense it might be worth it for me to take another look at what I'm comparing. I'll probably start with the grayscale image because I have a method to convert it to that as well!

Comment: If you will be processing a lot of similar images then you could also slice the image into several horizontal parts and process them differently. Assuming the bottom of the image is closer you can use more precision, but as you move to the top of the image (More objects in the distance) you could relax the checks a bit, then a lot, to remove the solid black in the image, but it's highly dependant on the image content.

Comment: @sorifiend that's a really good idea too that I hadn't thought of. I'm not sure how to splice images into separate parts but I could figure that out. For this image specifically, it would mean lower sensitivity on the bottom and higher on the top. I could also check to see if there is a large difference in black vs white pixels after it's done being changed and re-do that part of the image with higher or lower sensitivity. Looks like I've got a lot of work to do lol

Comment: The GUI code is irrelevant.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want to do/see (the "smaller intricacies" ??). And why don't you refer to the existing theory of edge detection ? Note that the original image shows much more than the ugly binary stuff.